# IntelliJ's structure tab: expand current view

Tags: intellij-idea

I really like the "structure" tab in IntelliJ, especially because I use regions a lot. Any elements in it are closed by default, and that's good for me, but I'd like the element my cursor is in to be expanded.

The idea is, here is a part of the code:

```
//region First
...
//endregion
//region Second
public void foo(){
  System.out.println("Hello");
}
//endregion
```

If my cursor is in the method 'foo', I'd like everything to be "closed" in the structure tab, except the region "Second" and the method "foo", which should be expanded.

I'm pretty sure there is a setting for that somewhere, but I couldn't find it by myself and google shows no results (probably because of how bad I am at putting words on it).

Here's a screenshot to be sure we mean the same thing:

[image: Screenshot of the "Structure" tab]

Comment: Do you have **Autoscroll from Source** option enabled in the structure view?

Comment: I don't know, how do you enable it? I'm using the default settings

Comment: The icon for this option hides in the Structure tool window under `>>`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, please write an answer and I will accept it. Weird though, the tooltip doesn't appear so I had to try every button one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the **Autoscroll from Source** option in the Structure tool window:

[image: Autoscroll from source]